# Why this rest call have a body of type InputStream even after marshalling it into json?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to learn apache camel and I having problems understanding why a call to a external api is returning a body of type InputStream and keep its type even after converting it to String and marshalling it into a json. I've already read all other questions of this type into stack overflow and nothing have solved my problem yet.

```
@Component
public class GetInfoRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String GET_INFO_TEST = "direct:get-info";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(GET_INFO_TEST)
            .routeId(GET_INFO_TEST)
            .streamCaching()
            .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
            .setHeader(RestConstants.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader(RestConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader(RestConstants.REST_HTTP_QUERY, constant("s=margarita"))
            // .setHeader("host", constant("thecocktaildb.com"))
            .to("rest:get:/api/json/v1/1/search.php?host=thecocktaildb.com")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .process(ex -> {
                DrinksDTO drinks = ex.getMessage().getBody(DrinksDTO.class);
                log.info("Drinks 1 : {}", drinks);

            })
            .log("${body}");
    }
}
```

Have tried marshalling and unmarshalling, removed the convertBodyTo(String.class) and use a different component to make the external call, in this case I've used the netty-http but the results were always the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should `unmarshal()` instead of `marshal()`.

Comment: Already did it and got
'''
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'a': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 5]
'''

Comment: what does your JSON look like?